# Hello everyone, MySQL dB table "migration_flows", where the date format is (ex."2000-02") as varchar, no day , is there a way to convert it to date?

Tags: mysql

| Field         |Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

| year_and_month|varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

I tried the following with no result:

1. select str_to_date(year_and_month,"%Y-%m-%d") from migration_flows;
2. select date_format(str_to_date("2021-10","%Y-%m"),"%Y-%m") from migration_flows;

What I want to do is alter the column's data type from varchar to date

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** do you want to convert? "2000-02" is not a data

Comment: I'll type the code attempts here as well:
> select str_to_date(year_and_month,"%Y/%m" from migration_flows;
ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from migration_flows' at line 1
===============================
> select date_format(str_to_date("2021-10","%Y/%m"),"%Y/%m");
Warning (code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '2021-10' for function str_to_date

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share all details in text form, not hidden in a screenshot

Comment: I am not allowed to post images yet, something about score points..

Comment: There's no need to post images. Feel free to post **text**

Comment: Thank you for getting involved and suggesting to me:
select str_to_date(year_and_month,"%Y/%m" from migration_flows;
------------------------------
select date_format(str_to_date("2021-10","%Y/%m"),"%Y/%m");

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: What whould be the desired result for a "date" like `2021-10`? First of October (ie `2021-10-01`), last of October (ie `2021-10-31`), something completely different?

Comment: Your varchar must have day and you can get month with `MONTH(varchar_value)` and `YEAR(varchar_value)`

Comment: the desired result would be (ie 2021-10-00) since no data for the day are provided.
 select str_to_date(year_and_month,"%Y-%m-%d") from migration_flows; returns the correct format but it does not change the data type from varchar to date.

Comment: You guys I did it! Thank you all so much. Steps I followed below:
1)alter table migration_flows add (application_date DATE);
2)update migration_flows set application_date=str_to_date(year_and_month,"%Y-%m-%d");
3) alter table migration_flows drop year_and_month;